# slideshow images displaying in wrong position on firefox

Tags: html, css, positioning

my image slideshow is displaying in the correct position on both chrome and explorer, but not with firefox. The images are placed inside the slideshow_box correctly but on firefox they are away up to the top right of the browser. The slideshow works using javascript.

does anyone have any idea why this is?

the html code:

```
 <div id="slideshow_box" class="clear">
           <div class="slides">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/buses.jpg" alt="bus in clydebank" </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/school_work.jpg" alt="school" </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/haven.jpg" alt="the haven kilmacolm" </a></li>
                </ul>
           </div><!--slides-->   
  </div><!--slideshow_box-->
```

the css:

```
#slideshow_box { 
background: url(../images/slideshow-box.png) no-repeat; height: 312px;  margin: 20px auto;
}

#slideshow_box .slides ul { 
list-style:none; position:relative; bottom: 50px; left: 40px; width: 750px; height: 250px; overflow: hidden;
 }
```

any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace to your img tag

**Replace this**

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/buses.jpg" alt="bus in clydebank" </a></li>
```

**into this**

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/buses.jpg" alt="bus in clydebank"/> </a></li>
```

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGVwN/1/)

Comment: thanks but that sorted out an issue with the display of my floating boxes in ie. Thats the thing with using transitional instead of strict I suppose lol. The slides are still displaying up top right!

Comment: could you detect any other way that firefox is displaying this incorrectly? check above comment. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `.slides ul` and the `#slideshow_box` have difference in height by `62px`. If you want to centering the `.slides ul` inside the container then the bottom value should be in `31px`. By the way I think it's better if you define the width value for `#slideshow_box` also.

Comment: the #slideshow box is 831px wide. I have added this and tried changing the bottom value to 31px but meses it up in ie and chrome. The images are still up in the top right of the browser window